how to automate the process of uploading the style.grass file in neo4j desktop
I am currently using Neo4j and wanted to update the default captions and the colors of the nodes. For that purpose, I used the :style command on the Neo4j browser.
Then I downloaded the style.grass file, made the changes in VSCode, and uploaded it back to the browser. However, I want to automate this process rather than manually uploading the style file every time.
Is there a way I can make changes to the file and have it reflect directly in the Neo4j browser without manual intervention? I’m looking for a dynamic approach to achieve this.
What I've Tried:
I found the following helpful links that guided me on how to update the style.grass file:

Neo4j Blog - 5 Big & Small Things to Love in Neo4j 2.2

Neo4j Community Discussion on Style

GitHub Pull Request on Neo4j Browser Styles (most helpful)


But for frequently changing styles, the manual approach doesn't seem promising.
